# Inflight dependency weird callback execution behaviour

Tags: node.js, callback

I was testing **NodeJS inflight libray** and below is the code for the test made.
The npm package is here - [inflight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inflight)

```
var inflight = require('inflight')  
function req(key, callback) {
    console.log("inside req --> ",key);
    callback = inflight(key, callback)
    console.log('callback --> ',callback);
    if (!callback) {
        console.log("returning from callback !!");
        return
    }
    console.log("calling settimeout !!")
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("inside setTimeout !!");
        callback(null, key)
    }, 8000)
}

const fn = (err, value) =>{
        console.log('callback called !!');
        if (err) console.log('You are in error !!');
        else console.log("value is -> ",value);
}

req('foo', fn)
console.log('first function returned !!');
req('foo', fn)
console.log('second function returned !!');
req('foo', fn)
console.log('third function returned !!');
```

Below is the output for the above code run on `NodeJS - 20.3.0`

```
inside req -->  foo
callback -->  [Function: f] { called: false }
calling settimeout !!
first function returned !!
inside req -->  foo
callback -->  null
returning from callback !!
second function returned !!
inside req -->  foo
callback -->  null
returning from callback !!
third function returned !!
inside setTimeout !!
callback called !!
value is ->  foo
callback called !!
value is ->  foo
callback called !!
value is ->  foo
```

My query is :

1. Why is , `callback called !! value is ->  foo` is being called thrice?
2. As per output, `console.log("returning from callback !!");` has been called twice which is expected as calling `req` thrice with same key `"foo"` will execute `callback` only once , which is also evident from the logs and seems correct.
3. But there is no reason why `"callback called"` should be printed thrice but should be printed only once.
4. Can anybody please explain below behaviour ?